# Проблема с переустановкой Ubuntu на VirtualBox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема с установкой ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64: cannot allocate kernel buffer; you need to load the kernel first

Ранее на виртуальной машине стояла ubuntu 20.4, возможно, старые файлы не были удалены до конца?

Comment: Оперативки в виртуалке достаточно?

Comment: Посмотрите вопрос в убунту: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465460/after-kernel-update-error-cannot-allocate-kernel-buffer-you-need-to-load-kern

Answer (score 1):

[Вот тут](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/linux-install/15994269?ysclid=ljzllh5y2s156747486) решена ваша проблема.

Единственная разница в том что на форуме рассматривается реальный комп, а у вас виртуалка. Однако думаю что вам нужно обратить внимание на настройки вашей виртуальной машины.